# Linear operator on $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\{E_1, E_2, ..., E_n\}$ be a collection of pairwise disjoint measurable subset of $(\mathbb{R}, m)$ ($m =$ Lebesgue measure on real line) with $0 < m(E_i) < \infty.$ Then for each $1 \leq p \leq \infty$, $$T(f) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\int_{E_i}f dm}{m(E_i)}1_{E_i}$$ is a well-defined linear operator on $L^p$ with $||T|| \leq 1.$

To check the well-defined property, does it mean to check $$\int_\mathbb{R} \Big(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\int_{E_i}f dm}{m(E_i)}1_{E_i}\Big)^p dm < \infty. $$ I am not sure how to verify that. It looks complicated. Also, can anyone point out something why $||T|| \leq 1 ?$

Comment: Can you calculate $\|\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i 1_{E_i}\|_{L^p}$ for given $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n \in \Bbb{R}$?

Comment: @PhoemueX I feel like you point out that $$\alpha_i = \frac{\int_{E_i}f dm}{m(E_i)}$$ ? Even so$$\int_\mathbb{R} (\sum \alpha_i 1_{E_i})^p dm$$ still need a long calculation to be performed.

Comment: Note that $E_i$ are pairwise disjoint, so the calculation is not messy at all!

Comment: To expand on the comment by @JohnMa: Note $(\sum \alpha_i 1_{E_i})^p = \sum \alpha_i^p 1_{E_i}$ (why?).